# Рамка вокруг текста с заголовком

Tags: html, css

Как сделать рамку вокруг `<p>` с заголовком по типу `<legend>` , знаю что они предназначенны для разного. Как сделать такого типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это сделано при помощи `h2` с белым задним фоном который закрывает линию, а так же `p` и рамки вокруг него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: green;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

fieldset legend {
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Photosession</legend>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi incidunt eligendi quos dolores beatae quam earum <a href="javascript:void(0);">architecto</a> eos rerum ab.</p>
</fieldset>
```